# Getting Bad Request 400 Error while Reading XML webpage using Razor

Tags: xml, razor

As the title states, the Html.Raw line in my code that reads the orderWebLink and converts it to a  string is getting a

> Bad Request (400) Error:
> SYSTEM.NET.WEBEXCEPTION: THE REMOTE SERVER RETURNED AN ERROR: (400) BAD REQUEST

I'm not displaying the actual URL because you have to login to my test website in order to see the code it generates. Here is the code shows when you go to orderWebLink above using a browser:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below:

    <OrderViewModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NashWrap.Web.Models">
      <UserId>1dde2e58-dd66-4863-89be-38e36c07b3ed</UserId>
    </OrderViewModel>
```

All I'm trying to do is get the text value of UserId and put it in a variable; but I can't seem to get passed this 400 error and I can't figure out why it wouldn't return code.

This is so I can fill in variables to pass to Google's Customer Reviews Survey. I have tried requesting this page using order.Load(orderWebLink) instead of HTML.Raw and also tried in ajax before this; but getting pretty much the same issue.

```
@using System.Xml;

@{
    string CurrentURL = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
@if (CurrentURL.Contains("/a/ordercomplete/"))
{
    string googleOrderID = CurrentURL.Substring(CurrentURL.IndexOf("/a/ordercomplete/") + 17);
    string CurrentWebsite = CurrentURL.Substring(0, CurrentURL.IndexOf("/a/ordercomplete/"));
    string googleUserID = "";
    string googleOrderEmail = "";
    string googleOrderCountry = "";
    string googleOrderCountryCode = "US";
    string errormessage = "";
    try
    {
        string orderWebLink = CurrentWebsite + "/api/order/" + googleOrderID;
        var html = Html.Raw(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(orderWebLink));
        XmlDocument order = new XmlDocument();
        order.LoadXml(html.ToString());
        foreach (XmlNode node1 in order)
        {
            googleUserID = node1["UserId"].InnerText;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errormessage = e.ToString();
    }
    @Html.Label("lblName", errormessage)
<!-- BEGIN GCR Opt-in Module Code -->
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderOptIn" async defer>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.renderOptIn = function () {
            window.gapi.load('surveyoptin', function () {
                window.gapi.surveyoptin.render(
                    {
                        // REQUIRED
                        "merchant_id": 6316095,
                        "order_id": "@googleOrderID",
                        "email": "@googleOrderEmail",
                        "delivery_country": "@googleOrderCountryCode",
                        "estimated_delivery_date": "2021-09-20",
                        "opt_in_style": "OPT_IN_STYLE",
                        "products": [{ "gtin": "123456789123" }, { "gtin": "123456789124" }]
                        //"opt_in_style": "CENTER_DIALOG"
                    });
            });
        }
    </script>
    <!-- END GCR Opt-in Module Code -->
    <!-- BEGIN GCR Language Code -->
    <script>
        window.___gcfg = {
            lang: 'en_US'
        };
    </script>
    <!-- END GCR Language Code -->
}
```

Comment: The server is telling you that your HTTP request is not one it understands.  That usually means the URI is malformed at some point after the server name.  Have you checked to see that the URI you're sending is the one you meant to send? Is it syntactically valid?  Is it using an expired local cookie?  Since you've chosen not to share the URI with the readers of your post, no one can answer these questions but you.

Comment: The URI goes here: https://qa.nashvillewraps.com/api/order/77d9627d-c194-4338-af17-c0b34cf6a89c
I echo'd it to make sure.
I copy that and put it in the browser and it goes to the right page with xml shown.

If someone wants to create an account, put something in the cart and checkout to get to their own confirmation page; they would get to the same place. Because this is a test website, no orders are actually placed and no credit cards are charged. Once you get to the 'Thank you for your order' page, take your order number in the URL and paste it after qa.nashvillewraps.com/api/order/

Comment: To your point, I could make the URL it goes to a static variable and it would still give me the same 400 error.